# How to add mutiple sections in uitableView in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create 3 section in my tableView but when I run this code I am getting only one section and it's itemsInSections. Can anyone help me to show all the sections and items in my tableview?

```
var itemsInSections: Array<Array<String>> = [["1A", "1B", "1C"], ["2A", "2B"], ["3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E"]]
var sections: Array<String> = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableview.dataSource = self
    self.tableview.delegate = self
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.itemsInSections[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let text = self.itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel!.text = text

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper method signatures.

This:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}
```

Needs to be:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}
```